# call function from external js (php) file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file where I keep all scripts so my pages wouldn't get messy (I have php file which generates required javascript).
My includes basically look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.php"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onClick="return blah();" />
</body>
</html>
```

script.php

```
<?php
    header("content-type: application/x-javascript");   
?>

    function blah()
    {
        alert("blah");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() 
    {});
```

In script.php there's jquery wrapper $(document).ready where I keep all jquery related stuff. The funny thing is, when I put function blah() inside this wrapper I get "blah is not defined" error, but when I put it outside - works perfectly. So, what could be the problem?

Comment: What are the contents of script.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely that's a simple scoping issue?

```
$(function(){

    window.blah = function() {

    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
function(){
    var foo = function(){
    }
    // Other stuff
}
```

... you are defining a private function that only exists inside the external function. If you want it global, you must either define it outside:

```
var foo = function(){
}
jQuery.ready(
    function(){
        // Other stuff
    }
);
```

... or append it to a global object, such as window:

```
jQuery.ready(
    function(){
        window.foo = function(){
        }
        // Other stuff
    }
);
```

It's worth noting that using external files does not change this.

### Answer to updated question:

blah() is **not** defined. Your function is called checkField().

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I was just copy-pasting so I forgot to change it. Thanks for notice.